# ios storekit not recieving consumable or non consumable products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i am trying to integrate inapp purchases in my ios app.

i had successfully configured items at itunes.connect

[image]

i had followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) of raywenderlich

i am successfully getting  free subscription inapp item in my device and can purchase it easily.
but i need consumable product to integrate in my app.
because a user can buy coins whenever he has no coins.

i dont see any product except free subscription items. stuck badly. please help

i am getting only this product  on my device. [image]

and i am getting this NSLog

```
Not purchased: com.shujat.inapp.consumable2
Not purchased: com.shujat.inapp.freesubs
Not purchased: com.shujat.inapp.nonconsumable1
Not purchased: com.shujat.inapp.consumable1
 Loaded list of products...
 Found product: com.shujat.inapp.freesubs free subs item 0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Good Day~

I also study this issue for several days.
And in my situation, I found the problem is in Apple web "iTunes Connect">"Contracts, Tax, and Banking".

1. Check the Master Agreement to find whether still has item (iOS Paid) in "Contract in Process".
   If YES, then fill-out the 3 "Set Up" - Contact Info, Bank Info, Tax Info - which are very detailed information. (It may need a long time to fill-out)
   [image]
2. After finished the 3 items, we may still wait apple to approve (I waited 1 day). Once the item (iOS Paid) becomes in "Contracts In Effect", then the app can see consumable or non consumable products.
   [image]

Hope this may help.

Comment: i had set up bank info succesfully . but dont know how to setup tax info and contact info.. can u provide some contact info section has a select button but no item is when i press that select button.. tax info is for U.S users only. not for pakistan users.

Comment: please can u guide me steps to fill out these sections

Answer (score 1):

Good Day~

I captured some figures of my situation for your reference.
Hope these can have some help to you.

[Contact Info]
1. In Contracts, Tax, Banking: Pressed Contact Info "Set up"
[image]

2. Then show Manage Your Contact Information: Pressed "Add new contact"
   [image]
3. Fill out detailed contact in the following view, then "Save".
   [image]
4. Finally, select your added contact in in the "Role Contact", then "Done".
   [image]

[Tax Info]
1. In Contracts, Tax, Banking: Pressed Tax Info "Set up"

2. Select U.S. Tax Form, or more the other two.
   [image]
3. To See if you're U.S. citizen, etc. Y/N
   [image]
4. To check if you have U.S. business. Y/N
   [image]
5. Certificate of Foreign Status of Beneficial Owner
   [image]
6. Confirm Again, then Done.
   [image]